# How do i hide annotations using a tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, tableview

I am trying to make it so that when i go to a table view, When I press a cell and it selects it that when I go back to the map my annotations are hidden. Or how would I select a cell and certain annotations hide when I select the cell, I'm a beginner programmer and have had little experience. I have tried looking at other programs but I have not figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

You could just remove the annotations for the map view in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [[self mapView] removeAnnotations:[[self mapView] annotations]];
}
```

Replace the `[[self mapView] annotations]` with an array of annotations if you want specific annotations to be removed when you select a certain cell. That logic is too ambiguous for me to help without further information.

Comment: what i am trying to do is hide specific annotations

Comment: You need some way to determine which annotations you want to hide. Then create an array of them and plug that into the `removeAnnotations:`.